# Problems reading MATLAB .mat files with a foreach loop in R

Tags: r, file-io, foreach, mat-file

I have over a thousand matlab files that I want to read into R. I use the R.matlab package to read them and I would like to parallel the operation.

However, once I call the loop (I am generating a single data set from all the .mat files) I get an error:

> Error in { :    task 1 failed - "not possible to encounter function
>   "readMat""

(I translated the part of the error between "", since my R is not in english)

without the foreach command, everything goes fine, but it takes too long. Here is the code

```
library(R.matlab)
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

a = list.files()
data <- readMat(a[1])

for(j in 2:length(a))  {

  data1 <- readMat(a[j])

  if (is.null(data1)==FALSE) {
      data <- rbind.fill(data,data1)
  }}
  print(j)
}
```

with the foreach command I get the above error. Here is the code:

```
    library(R.matlab)
    library(plyr)
    library(foreach)
    library(doParallel)


cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)

    a = list.files()
    data <- readMat(a[1])

    foreach(j = 2:length(a)) %dopar% {

      data1 <- readMat(a[j])

      if (is.null(data1)==FALSE) {
          data <- rbind.fill(data,data1)
      }}
      print(j)
    }
```

Does it mean foreach and readMat should not be used together?

Comment: Are you forgetting to close the second set of parentheses before the `%dopar%`?

Comment: ops, a typo... but it is closed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if anyone is wondering, I forgot to export `R.matlab` to each cluster node. Just needed to add `.packages` argument inside the `foreach` call

```
library(R.matlab)
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)


cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)

a    <- list.files()
data <- readMat(a[1])

foreach(j = 2:length(a), .packages = c("plyr", "doParallel",
                                       "R.matlab")) %dopar% {

  data1 <- readMat(a[j])

  if (!is.null(data1)) {
      data <- rbind.fill(data,data1)
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to `print(j)` with this? While it is looping?